# ffmpeg vstats command

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to dump the bit rate per frame of a video. I am trying to get this information using `-vstats` command. When I run this command -

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vstats
```

it shows at least one file should be defined.

I would really appreciate if anyone could suggest me any approach to get bit rate per frame.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `ffprobe`, here, which just dumps the info about a video without trying to write an output.